# Why does the pKa - pKb relationship hold when Kw holds for the autoionization of water?

Tags: acid-base

The relationship is commonly expressed as:

$$pK_a + pK_b = pK_w = 14$$

or

$$K_a * K_b = 10^{-14}$$

This holds because

$$K_a = \frac{[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}$$
$$K_b = \frac{[OH^-][HA]}{[A^-]}$$
$$K_aK_b = \frac{[H^+][A^-]}{[HA]}\frac{[OH^-][HA]}{[A^-]}=[H^+][OH^-]=K_w=10^{-14}$$

$K_w$ is the autoionization constant of water, or the equilibrium constant of water as it reacts with itself in equilibrium. This has the measured value of $10^{-14}$.

But isn't this value measured when water is all by itself, reacting with itself in autoionization? Why does the value hold when, say, acid is added into the water? Why are the concentrations of protons and hydronium ions ($OH^-$) still both equal to $10^-7$?

Comment: "Why are the concentrations of protons and hydronium ions still both equal to 10^-7?" Nobody said they're both $10^{-7}$, only that its product is $10^{-14}$. If $ab = 100$, it doesn't imply that $a = b = 10$.

Comment: @orthocresol Okay, but still the product is measured for autoionization if water. Why does it hold for a solution where acid or base is added?

Comment: Because it's an equilibrium constant, which is always a constant at equilibrium (hence the name), regardless of the exact concentrations of the reacting species, and regardless of how that equilibrium was reached.

Comment: @orthocresol But arent equilibrium constants reaction specific? A different one for water reacting with water, and another for acid reacting with water?

Comment: Yes, but the first is $K_\mathrm{w}$, and the second is $K_\mathrm{a}$, which are different. The point here is not about whether $K_\mathrm{w} = K_\mathrm{a}$ (it obviously isn't), but rather about $K_\mathrm{w}$ being the same regardless of whether you're applying it to a neutral solution, acidic solution, or basic solution. Also, when I say $K_\mathrm{w}$ is the same, this means that $[\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-14}$, it doesn't mean anything about either $[\ce{H+}]$ or $[\ce{OH-}]$.

Comment: @orthocresol But why is $K_w$ equal to 14? It is so because for water in equilibrium in autoionization at room temperature the concentrations of both protons and hydronium are $10^{-7}$. But this is for one reaction only, the autoionization of water. Why is the product of concetrations the same in other reactions like acid in equilibrium with water?

Comment: The OP may mean Kw conventionally implicitly involves implied constant concentration(activity) of water, that decreases when a solute is added. But most of equlibriums are considered for rather diluted solutions where c << 55.x mol H2O/L, so the difference is neglected.

Comment: No, you have it the wrong way round. $K_\mathrm{w}$ is equal to $10^{-14}$ (not $14$), but this is **not** because $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-7}$! It is the exact opposite: in pure water, we have  $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-7}$ *because* $K_\mathrm{w} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-14}$ *and* because in pure water, the stoichiometry of dissociation dictates that $[\ce{H+}] = [\ce{OH-}]$, *hence* both of them are $10^{-7}$.

Comment: Also, $\ce{OH-}$ is *hydroxide*, not hydronium. Hydronium is quite the opposite.